# Starting a transition on specific time in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, transition

I made an `transition` for an `imageview` and I want to play it when the time in Android Phone is for example **10:00 AM**, then how can I do this? I tried to do this with `AlarmManager` but it's of no use! It's not getting work done, is it possible to do?

Comment: Where is ImageView? In your app?

Comment: Below `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. I can post my `MainActivity.java` and `main.xml` is you want.

Comment: Have you tried to open the app and try simple animation when AlarmManager recieves the event?

Comment: Nope I haven't tried that, can you show me an example? It would be great!

Comment: Show what you have done so far? BroadCastReciever? AlarmManager?

Comment: I made `AlarmManager` then a `BroadcastReceiver` and in activity AlarmManager.java I extended `Service` but from service I was able to push notifications, toasts or start activity on specific time but i was not able to start transitions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the **onRecieve** method put the following:

```
Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, YourScheduledActivity.class);
scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);
```

And inside the **onCreate** method of *YourScheduledActivity*, we do transition.

Comment: I have used this in past. Should work. Just give it a try and say. Best of luck

Comment: Ohkay bro Thanks! I will see if it works, it should work. But if it'll not can you help me again?